# Android - MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage - Unable to create file

Tags: android, mediastore

I'm experiencing some weird problems related to Media.insertImage method
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#insertImage(android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.graphics.Bitmap,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

```
private Uri createTemporaryUri(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    fixMediaDirForKitkat();
    String savedPath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(requestTarget.getMyFragment().getActivity().getContentResolver(), bitmap, "someone_tmp", null);
    return Uri.parse(savedPath);
}

private void fixMediaDirForKitkat()
{
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    if(sdcard != null) {
        File mediaDir = new File(sdcard, "DCIM/Camera");
        if( !mediaDir.exists()) {
            mediaDir.mkdirs();
        }
    }
}
```

For some kitkat devices (4.4 - 4.4.4) without using method fixMediaDirForKitkat insertImage function sometimes returns null. After adding method I'm experiencing:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create new file: /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/1480524677437.jpg
android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.insertImage (MediaStore.java:1008)
some.one.PhotoUploader.createTemporaryUri (PhotoUploader.java:166)
some.one.PhotoUploader.beginImageUpload (PhotoUploader.java:145)
some.one.registration.RegisterFragment.onActivityResult (RegisterFragment.java:107)
```

Does anything else need to be initialized? Any hack or workaround here is available? Device doesn't have a SD card/space? Unable to create new file tells me nothing ;-)

Any suggestions highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you don't give permission then give permission to your android manifest file and if give ignore it.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

You want to create directory then follow this code

```
public static String downloadPath = "/DCIM/Camera";
File fileDir = new File(downloadPath);

if (fileDir.isDirectory()) {
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(downloadPath, filename);
    } else {
        fileDir.mkdirs();
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(downloadPath, filename);
    }
```

**OR**
Issue seems it be related with [Android Runtime Permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) introduced in Android 6.0

When your app targeting API Level 23, by default all the permission is false you have to request permission dialog and approve the permission before using that into your app.

Comment: Hi Ninja, thanks for answer. All things about permissions you mentioned are already implemented and works fine (tested both API below and above 23). Problem occurs only on some devices with KITKAT.

Comment: @Jacek If it is helped then please Up vote because some one get help

Comment: @Jacek - i face the same issue, will u pls share how you fixed this ? thanks